# V6-I6 and V-vi6 chord successions

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

Why are V6-I6 and V-vi6 inappropriate chordal successions (when harmonizing for the Common Practice Period)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the successions and see what leaps to the eye. We'll use C major for simplicity's sake.

[image]

The first one, Ex. 1, has a very nice bass for a cadential progression... in E minor. That's the essential problem with it - B isn't acting as a leading tone, it's acting as if it were a dominant root. Put the C chord in root position, and you've got both a logical bass for a move to C and a logical use of the leading tone.

The second one, Ex. 2, also has a very nice bass for a cadential progression... in C major. It makes for a deceptive progression, but maybe too deceptive?

Having said all that, though, there is nothing really objectionable in the voice leading other than that you've got a rising fourth/falling fifth in the bass that *isn't* a movement from root to root and that the leading tone isn't going where expected in Ex. 1.

Ex. 1 thus gives absolutely no feeling of being a perfect (authentic) cadence, and Ex. 2 undercuts the sense of a deceptive cadence (a little bit) by moving to the inversion instead of root position. The latter is less of a problem than the former in that the unexpected movement of the leading tone is part of a deceptive progression anyway.

It would not surprise me, however, to find that both of these successions have seen use as passing phenomena in the middle of phrases.

Answer (score 1):

Because the V6 (first inversion) has the leading tone as the bass note. During the common practice period, if the leading tone was on the bass or the soprano voice, it would go to the tonic.

So, following V6 you would need the tonic as the bass note in the next chord; can't be any kind of inversion. Just root position.

I don't see anything wrong with V-vi6